# One summary for multiple test files using python unittest

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing

I wanna make automated testing for my python project but I'm not sure about the correct way to use `unittest` module.

All of my test files are currently in one folder and have this format:

```
import unittest
class SampleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testMethod(self):
        # Assertion here
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Then I run

```
find ./tests -name "*_test.py" -exec python {} \;
```

When there are three test files, it outputs

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

It printed one summary for each test file. So the question is what can I do to make it print only one test summary, eg `Ran 5 tests in 0.001s`?

Thanks in advance

*And I don't want to install any other module*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are invoking Python multiple times, and each process does not have any knowledge about rest of them. You need to run Python once and use unittest discover mechanism.

Run in shell:

```
python -m unittest discover
```

Depending on what is your project structure and naming conventions you may want to tweak discovery params, e.g. change `--pattern` option, as described in help:

```
Usage: python -m unittest discover [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -v, --verbose         Verbose output
  -f, --failfast        Stop on first fail or error
  -c, --catch           Catch Ctrl-C and display results so far
  -b, --buffer          Buffer stdout and stderr during tests
  -s START, --start-directory=START
                        Directory to start discovery ('.' default)
  -p PATTERN, --pattern=PATTERN
                        Pattern to match tests ('test*.py' default)
  -t TOP, --top-level-directory=TOP
                        Top level directory of project (defaults to start
                        directory)
```

While you said *I don't want to install any other module*, I'd still recommend using another test runner. There are quite few out there, [pytest](http://docs.pytest.org/) or [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.io/) to name a few.